# Styles not being applied when use selectors

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

I can't find a solution - everything appears correct, and I have tried validating the code. No problems. When I apply the styles to every `<p>` (no selector), it shows up fine. When I use the selectors, nothing. When I move the selectors to the top of the `<style>` tags, all the styles disappear. So clearly I'm missing something and these selectors are wrong somehow. Any help?

```css
p.indented{
  margin-left: 3em;
}

p#borderParagraph{
  border: 6px double black; 
  border-radius: 20px; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding: .75em;
}
```

```html
<p class=“indented”>Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consquat. Luis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

<p id=“borderParagraph”>Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consquat. Luis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
```

Comment: replace `“` and `”` with `"` and it works.

Comment: `p#borderParagraph` has no sense. `#` marks id which is and must be unique

Comment: The browser sometimes stores your files in a cache in order to load the files quickly. you may need to refresh in order to invalidate the cache

Comment: @Banzay in a way, you're right... But it should work (Think about LESS or SASS code `p  { color:blue;  &#special  { color:red; }  }`)

Comment: @Banzay `p#borderParagraph` is perfectly acceptable CSS. If there were more elements with the same `id` in the markup, that's a different story.

Comment: you are not using double or single quotes while giving class to elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `”` instead of `"` or `'`

```html
<style>
        p.indented{
            margin-left: 3em;
        }

        p#borderParagraph{
            border: 6px double black; 
            border-radius: 20px; 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: .75em;
        }
    </style>

    <h3>Works</h3>
    <p class="indented">Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consquat. Luis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <p id='borderParagraph'>Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consquat. Luis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>

     <h3>Not working</h3>
    
    <p class=”indented”>Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consquat. Luis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course it was the text editor I was using. Now if I could just get it to quit changing to smart quotes automatically...

Comment: This is another question ^^ But you should look at [Javascript replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function. `str = str.replace(new RegExp('”', 'g'), '"')`

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you just need to use regular quotes `"` or `'` - not the "smart" quotes that some word processors use.

Also, your CSS selectors can be simplified.  You don't need to specify both the element **and** the selector, just the selector is sufficient unless you have specific needs for the same class to look different on different elements.  Generally this is not advised though.

```css
.indented {
  margin-left: 3em;
}

#borderParagraph {
  border: 6px double black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .75em;
}
```

```html
<p class="indented">Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consquat. Luis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

<p id="borderParagraph">Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consquat. Luis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also thanks for the clarification - I knew I didn't necessarily need the p in front, but I never knew which way was better.

Comment: Your second point is out of the question, `p#id` is non conventional but valid (and `p.class` very useful, to gain only 2 chars). In this case you can also talk about [naming convention](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849) `.border-paragraph` instead of camel case, and event `.bordered` cause paragraph are already specify with `p.bordered` . A good stackoverflow answer should answer to only one problem at time.

Comment: True and point taken.  I'm just trying to help explain the answer to the question along with some help for a (presumably) new developer to help make their code a bit easier to read, write, and use.